# clang-format: always break all parameters, one per line

Tags: c++, formatting, clang-format

I would like my function prototypes / definitions to always separate out parameters into separate lines, regardless of total length. An otherwise default `.clang-format` with options

```
BasedOnStyle: Chromium
AlignAfterOpenBracket: 'AlwaysBreak'
BinPackArguments: 'false'
BinPackParameters: 'false'
ColumnLimit: '80'
```

gives the following formatting

```
  void foo(float a, float b);

  void foo(float a, float b, float c, float d, float e, float f, float g);

  void
  foo(float a, float b, float c, float d, float e, float f, float g, float h);

  void foo(
      float a,
      float b,
      float c,
      float d,
      float e,
      float f,
      float g,
      float h,
      float i);
```

I would like for them to all be broken consistently, one parameter per line, like so:

```
  void foo(
      float a,
      float b);

  void foo(
      float a,
      float b,
      float c,
      float d,
      float e,
      float f,
      float g);

  void foo(
      float a,
      float b,
      float c,
      float d,
      float e,
      float f,
      float g,
      float h);

  void foo(
      float a,
      float b,
      float c,
      float d,
      float e,
      float f,
      float g,
      float h,
      float i);
```

Is there any mechanism to do this?

Bonus for the bounty: I would additionally like my member function implementations to split on the return type, class name, and function name, so e.g. instead of this:

```
float A::foo(float a, float b)
{
// ...
}
```

I'd like this:

```
float
A::
foo(float a,
    float b)
{
// ...
}
```

Comment: Also interested in this. As far as I can tell this is not supported and I'm completely surprised by this.

Comment: I think your parameter formatting is not supported. 
However, the break after return type is possible using the AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType option with All or AllDefinitions value.

Comment: I've been trying to do the same thing. I prefer the parameters on each line, but the inconsistency of having the 2 styles looks way worse than sticking to the first style. Did anyone make a request to llvm to add this option?

Answer (score 3):

**It's not possible.**

The only what can be tuned is when a return type is split. By setting penalty `PenaltyReturnTypeOnItsOwnLine: 1000`, it turns this line

```cpp
void
foo(float a, float b, ...
```

into

```cpp
void foo(
    float a, float b, ...
```

and by `AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: TopLevelDefinitions` format

```cpp
float A::foo(float a, float b)
{
// ...
}
```

to

```
float
A::foo(float a, float b) {
  // ...
}
```