# clang-format: can't force function parameters and return value attributes on separate lines

Tags: c++, clang-format

The problem I am having has already been asked at least 2 times already:
[clang-format force each argument / parameter to own line when column exceeded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50318053/clang-format-force-each-argument-parameter-to-own-line-when-column-exceeded) and [clang-format: always break all parameters, one per line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50660455/clang-format-always-break-all-parameters-one-per-line). But none of those proposed solutions seem to fix my issue.

What I am trying to achieve is to have code similar how Microsoft has it in it's headers:

- each return value type attribute/qualifier (`static`/`inline`/SAL macros) on their own line
- each function parameter (even if there is only 1 parameter) on their own separate line

Here is my clang-format file:

```
---
AccessModifierOffset: -4
AlignAfterOpenBracket: BlockIndent
AlignArrayOfStructures: Left
AlignConsecutiveAssignments:
  Enabled: false
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations:
  Enabled: false
AlignConsecutiveBitFields:
  Enabled: false
AlignConsecutiveMacros:
  Enabled: false
AlignEscapedNewlines: DontAlign
AlignOperands: AlignAfterOperator
AlignTrailingComments:
  Kind: Never
AllowAllArgumentsOnNextLine: false
AllowAllParametersOfDeclarationOnNextLine: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None
AllowShortBlocksOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortCaseLabelsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortEnumsOnASingleLine: false
AllowShortIfStatementsOnASingleLine: Never
AllowShortLambdasOnASingleLine: None
AllowShortLoopsOnASingleLine: false
AlwaysBreakAfterDefinitionReturnType: All
AlwaysBreakAfterReturnType: All
AlwaysBreakBeforeMultilineStrings: false
AlwaysBreakTemplateDeclarations: Yes
BinPackArguments: false
BinPackParameters: false
BitFieldColonSpacing: Both
BraceWrapping:
  AfterFunction: true
  BeforeElse: true
  AfterCaseLabel: true
  AfterClass: false
  AfterControlStatement: Always
  AfterEnum: false
  AfterNamespace: false
  AfterStruct: false
  AfterUnion: false
  AfterExternBlock: false
  BeforeCatch: true
  BeforeLambdaBody: true
  BeforeWhile: true
  IndentBraces: false
  SplitEmptyFunction: false
  SplitEmptyRecord: false
  SplitEmptyNamespace: false
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
BreakAfterAttributes: Always
IndentWidth: 4
InsertBraces: true
InsertNewlineAtEOF: true
Language: Cpp
NamespaceIndentation: None
PointerAlignment: Right
QualifierAlignment: Leave
ReferenceAlignment: Pointer
RemoveBracesLLVM: false
SortIncludes: Never
SpaceAfterCStyleCast: false
SpaceAfterLogicalNot: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: false
SpaceAroundPointerQualifiers: After
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCaseColon: false
SpaceBeforeCpp11BracedList: false
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: false
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
SpaceBeforeParens: Custom
SpaceBeforeParensOptions:
  AfterControlStatements: true
  AfterForeachMacros: true
  AfterFunctionDeclarationName: false
  AfterFunctionDefinitionName: false
  AfterIfMacros: true
  AfterOverloadedOperator: false
  AfterRequiresInClause: false
  AfterRequiresInExpression: false
  BeforeNonEmptyParentheses: false
SpaceBeforeRangeBasedForLoopColon: false
SpaceBeforeSquareBrackets: false
SpaceInEmptyBlock: false
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 1
SpacesInAngles: Never
SpacesInCStyleCastParentheses: false
SpacesInConditionalStatement: false
SpacesInContainerLiterals: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpacesInSquareBrackets: false
Standard: c++11
TabWidth: 4
UseTab: Never
```

I used [this](https://clang-format-configurator.site/) site to test out the results (also tested locally with clang-format version 17), but this is the final result:

```
struct SampleStruct {
    SampleStruct() = default;
    virtual ~SampleStruct() = default;

    /* How it should look:
    static
    inline
    bool
    IsTrue(
        _In_opt_ const SampleStruct *Node
    )
    {
        if (!Node)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Node->value;
    }
    */
    static inline bool
    IsTrue(_In_opt_ const SampleStruct *Node)
    {
        if (!Node)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return Node->value;
    }

    bool value = true;
};

/* How it should look:
typedef
_Function_class_(SampleFunctionClass)
void
__cdecl
SampleFunctionClass(
    _Inout_ SampleStruct *Obj,
    _In_ void *Ptr
);
*/
typedef _Function_class_(SampleFunctionClass
) void __cdecl SampleFunctionClass(_Inout_ SampleStruct *Obj, _In_ void *Ptr);
```

It seems, that it has no problems when there are multiple parameters to a function. Also tried to play around with `ColumnLimit` (set it to 0 or 1), but it did not help.
I know i still have to add SAL macros, but i first want to sort out the parameter problem.

Comment: Have you tried [clang-format detector](https://www.clangpowertools.com/blog/getting-started-with-clang-format-detector.html) to generate the `.clang-format` settings as detected from a given source file?

Comment: That never worked, because it tries to approximate the format, but it generates something that is worse than the visual studio formatter.